# Oracle SQL: select for weekday and converting column to date

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm having a database with column (with datatype VARCHAR20)

| Created |
| --- |
| 2020-01-01T20:30:20.207Z |
| 2020-01-04T23:10:00.242Z |

In the end I want to be able to filter for a certain weekday. My first step in order to do that is applying

```
SELECT *
FROM mydatabase
WHERE TO_DATE(CREATED, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFF"Z"') BETWEEN TO_DATE ('2020-01-02T10:39:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFF"Z"') AND TO_DATE('2020-01-03T15:39:00.000Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FFF"Z"');
```

to see if conversion corresponding to my ISO8601 format works. Unfortunately, I get the error "ORA-01821 - "date format not recognized"". Would be great if someone could tell me how to accomplish my task of filtering according to a certain weekday and if I'm on the right track.

All the best.

Comment: Moral of the story is store your data in the correct format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do:

```
where to_char(to_date(substr(created, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Dy') = 'Mon'
```

For internationalization purposes, you can insist this is in English using a third parameter:

```
select to_char(to_date(substr(created, 1, 10), 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 'Dy') = 'Mon'
```

Or use the native language of the database.

This converts the first ten characters to a date and then converts that to a weekday.

Comment: Great answer, works, except for 'Mon', which in my case has to be 'Mo' (language dependent? If yes, how can I set it to English?). And second question: can one apply the method you used (with different offsets for the substring) for querying a range for the time (i.e. between 14:00 and 15:00)?

Comment: @kallikles . . . Obviously, the comparison should be to whatever language you prefer.  You can force `to_char()` to use English using a third parameter, if you want.